# c++ sort object vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I've a question regarding sorting of object in a vector

my object consists of x,y and civ. so I would like to know how do I sort the value of the civ in an descending order but at the same time retaining the value of x and y attached to it..

```
original
X: 4 Y: 5 CIV: 10
X: 3 Y: 2 CIV: 30
X: 3 Y: 3 CIV: 05

sorted
X: 3 Y: 2 CIV: 30
X: 4 Y: 5 CIV: 10
X: 3 Y: 3 CIV: 05
```

missionplan.cpp

```
for(int j=0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for(int i = j; i < topfive.size(); i++)
        {
            if(topfive[i].getcivIndex() < topfive[i].getcivIndex)
            {
                topfive[i].swap(topfive[i]);

            }
        }
        pointtwoD = topfive.at(i);//display all data starting from the first index
        pointtwoD.displayPointdata();
    }
```

Comment: Read about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score 0):

You have a misktake in your code.

```
if(topfive[i].getcivIndex() < topfive[i].getcivIndex) //The second i should be j
{
     topfive[i].swap(topfive[i]); // which should be topfive[j].swap(topfive[i])
}
```